# Hiding password field in command line

Tags: c, security, unix, freebsd

I am writing a system service on FreeBSD where I need to take user credentials to verify identity, something like this:

`./compression_bin -i <input_file> --type=<type> --password=<secret key>`

Here, the secret key is used to authenticate user before compressing the given file. Currently, the secret key shows up in history which is bad and can be exploited. Is there a way where above can be invoked without displaying password field:

`./compression_bin -i <input_file> --type=<type> --password=*********`

Comment: If you are writing this program, let it read the password from a file and call it like `./compression_bin -i <input_file> --type=<type> --passwordfile=some_file` or implement an option for reading the password from `stdin` or from `/dev/tty`.

Comment: This is a losing battle. There will always be a small amount of time between process initialization and when you can replace the characters where any attacker could grab that password. MySQL used to do command-line authentication this way, but now if you do it you get a *BIG WARNING* about how it's not secure. Use a password file. Don't take it as an argument.

Comment: It's not just the history. **It is also shown by "ps"!** As already said by Bodo: Use a file. Alternate solution: Use stdin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The history will always record the text of the commands as they were issued.  You could conceivably go back and modify the history file, but not only is that nasty, it still affords a window within which the password can be read.

Moreover, that's not even the easiest exploit. If the password is given on the command line then there are other ways it can be read while the command is running, such as from the output of the `ps` command, which is accessible to all users.

So don't take the password as a command-line argument.  Read it from a file or from the standard input or from a socket, or some other such thing.